# Calculating Probabilities using a cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

For (b)

Pr(X greater than or equal to 2) = ?

The textbook says as such but I am confused:

Pr(X greater than or equal to 2) 
= 1 - pr(X less than 2)

I do not understand why they re-write the probability, because doesn't Pr(X greater than or equal to 2) fit in the domain: x greater than 0? Why must we re-write this?

the answer then goes on to solve this

1 - F(2)

^ I dont understand why we can substitute 2 into F(x) only after re-writing the equation as 1- F(x) and not simply F(x)

Comment: sorry edited***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot substitute $2$ into $F(x)$ because $F(x)$ is by definition equal to $\Pr\{X\le x\}$ and we are looking for the probability $\Pr\{X\ge2\}$.

We have that
$$
\Pr\{X\ge2\}=1-\Pr\{X<2\}
$$
and
$$
\Pr\{X<2\}=\Pr\{X\le2\}
$$
since the random variable $X$ is continuous.

So the answer is
$$
1-F(2).
$$

Comment: Would it be allowed to write Pr(X≤2) instead of Pr(X<2) ... they are the same thing....so I can write either in my working out - am i correct?

Comment: @confused In general, $\Pr\{X\le2\}=\Pr\{X<2\}+\Pr\{X=2\}$, but in this case $\Pr\{X=2\}=0$ since the random variable $X$ is [continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Random_Variables#Continuous_probability_distribution).

Comment: @confused I'm glad I could help!